# Making input text uneditable before making it editable again in 3 seconds using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, prop

I have an input text, and when you press enter, it's suppose to make the input text uneditable, before making it editable again in 3 seconds. But it's not working for some reason. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<input type = "text" id = "text">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(function(){

$("#text").keyup(function(e){ 
    if (e.which == 13) {
    $("#text").prop("readonly", true);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("#text").prop("readonly", false);
}, 3000);

}); //end of if (e.which == 13)

}); //end of $(function())

</script>
```

Comment: use $("#text").attr("readonly","readonly") and $("text").removeAttr("readonly")

Comment: @Omidam81 The jQuery is including from googleapis. The version I included is 1.11.3.

Comment: @RezaMansouri Is it because the version doesn't support it or something?

Comment: I don't know but, I used to do it this way. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo in if closing , there is an additional parenthesis remove it

```js
$(function() {
  $("#text").keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $("#text").prop("readonly", true);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#text").prop("readonly", false);
      }, 3000);
    } //end of if (e.which == 13)
  //-^--- remove ) from here
  }); //end of $(function())
});
// also add this closing
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text">
```

Comment: You know what, from now on, every time I run into something that doesn't work again, I'm going to auto-format the code and see if I'm missing or having additional parenthesis' or not. *facepalms.

Comment: Wait. Did YOU auto-format the code? If you did, where did you do it? I tried it in phpFiddle, but they separates the parenthesis and and the brackets, and I think it makes it harder to read.

Comment: @frosty :  i have done it using SO snippet.... almost every fiddle there is an option **tidy** for formating

Answer (score 0):

depending on your jquery version on of the following will work:

```
 $("#text").attr('readonly', true); //this work for older jquery version
```

or

```
 $("#text").prop('readonly', true);  //for new jquery version
```

for removing readonly attribute you can use removeAttr()

```
$("#text").removeAttr('readonly');
```